# Powershell: Odd output when using foreach and listbox

Tags: powershell, listbox, foreach

I'm currently experimenting and trying to get this code:

```
$processnames = Get-Process | select name 
foreach ($processname in $processnames)
{
[void]$AD_list_current.Items.Add($processnames)

}
```

to output in a listbox. It outputs as it is but for some reason it keeps displaying in the listbox as:[image]

Does anyone know why this is?

It would be greatly apprechiated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `$processnames` instead of `$processname` to your list.

That's an array.

As per Joey's comment, the default `ToString()` method will show the type name, which is `System.Object`.

Comment: It's an array and the default ToString() implementation yields the type name. Nothing in particular to do with interpreting as object.

Comment: I added $processname instead of $processnames and it worked. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 3):

Here's a shorter way to add all process names:

```
$list.Items.AddRange( (Get-Process | select name) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[void]$AD_list_current.Items.Add($($processnames))
```